# Postfix mail going into spam on Gmail and Hotmail (tried everything, still can't make it ok)

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, vps, linode

Somebody help please, this isn't duplicate. I've been through all the answers I could find all across web, tried different things but I still can't make it not to go in spam folder.

Running postfix, dovecot, mysql, spamassassin with Let's Encrypt SSL, DKIM valid, SPF passes and even DMARC passes, PTR record is set. I've even configured ClamAV and Amavis thinking that might help, but no, still goes to spam folder.

hostname is mail.devexus.net

/etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain locahost
127.0.0.1       mail.devexus.net mail.devexus.net

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Here is header of one mail that went to spam

```
Delivered-To: ******da0@gmail.com
Received: by 10.223.157.140 with SMTP id p12csp2909027wre;
    Sun, 25 Feb 2018 07:51:44 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AH8x2255Y4AJYhkzAtmNyXjg6EXKfjKkDdW4PEpRAU7WNCosBkiBYoIY9mVfHqjwzW8JIO8FXzBr
X-Received: by 10.223.153.51 with SMTP id x48mr6599051wrb.216.1519573904411;
    Sun, 25 Feb 2018 07:51:44 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1519573904; cv=none;
    d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    b=PQ3hgo3pcKq5shaqCnhyL/LuZi4XTqCYeRzs2z+i3idyjKojNI6W0dOwUcsQ6HvLVP
     06ydM+/EskBiSPCq/3XJA8hjZtZJM3gEn1ih/3jgQ+xX9OorFijNJbx5SDI32VQzgqI7
     baDdWnY1kzadUt/O5Tvq3UamrL4LXuMu6MPTCWdcyIf30kj5YbZEExRWm6OT5ajxJpzH
     Z8v5hfhpMrhmKzjZOIIz0zqfvEU5tWioWsfeT7CeY0Xwr20g2sY7vsgiduPc4dQW8Ap/
     c6MjjqnvBZZtR6az7wC1tDBwUabStYd3awDdeKKAM0T5CEH4vvp3cx29438Kld97vO22
     WJcg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    h=content-language:thread-index:mime-version:message-id:date:subject
     :to:from:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
    bh=Z3lrmhLvqaXWgZHr1L2mZDXf0ZVz4IExOW69HEUJfb4=;
    b=0BJAYc50K6tzZfso9gBAkj+fKwvgBzKLqbg0lY8wVFufwmt+E87QLNLL/1lAkumYzH
     FwvI0tl0iwgI+NTZZlwombAkk/YQ794g0HwPy25ytHuJWZPLMuiM+AUnyyESdFmvt19q
     nwuiQBxQVf40UdheSZsEZdF4ya1ryxcCWPQe6b3rAJ5dxpkmexbRAAi/8+j/PNZhHH7w
     NB91BWUez779FUUSJ514lorX+EslrdbdnxybSjsuOQQvtk+jiIrjAYBsimMW7ERXhXDf
     eKNXKDHlHqxe7Yxy5YwEccbQgNAzUtYYyBWqSL4gXObxBpoSwsxO6aZKFIYxmb+SBML/
     dHkg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@devexus.net header.s=dkim header.b=emYycQeQ;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of ivan@devexus.net designates 139.162.133.174 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=ivan@devexus.net;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=devexus.net
Return-Path: <ivan@devexus.net>
Received: from mail.devexus.net (mail.devexus.net. [139.162.133.174])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id g85si303716wmc.109.2018.02.25.07.51.43
    for <******da0@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Sun, 25 Feb 2018 07:51:43 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ivan@devexus.net designates 139.162.133.174 as permitted sender) client-ip=139.162.133.174;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@devexus.net header.s=dkim header.b=emYycQeQ;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of ivan@devexus.net designates 139.162.133.174 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=ivan@devexus.net;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=devexus.net
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]) by mail.devexus.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 55F9C40611 for <******ada0@gmail.com>; Sun, 25 Feb 2018 16:51:43 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at devexus.net
Received: from mail.devexus.net ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mail.devexus.net [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id kqtOTuX741RJ for <*****ada0@gmail.com>; Sun, 25 Feb 2018 16:51:42 +0100 (CET)
Received: from DESKTOP7GKF188 (unknown [178.255.152.117]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by mail.devexus.net (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 866AC40610 for <*******ada0@gmail.com>; Sun, 25 Feb 2018 16:51:42 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=devexus.net; s=dkim; t=1519573902; bh=P9Z5q9aBS0MUY38+pDbc0mHCDxxG0wexgOdThxSzofY=; h=From:To:Subject:Date:From; b=emYycQeQi2isvGEuU4MLbaI1lZ2mQRW18Um4bHJZtj1zCiQepXd190e9mFwI4/uAO
 99pFnrrYAQ5Ps6RDgOvt3CB1wkix9tA+olq7v2KZeHdKhOT1VFDsSKP3Juz6b0cPAo
 jTiZe2D+g+f6/v6g8AN3qm12xVirCMdJGITlBJic=
From: "Ivan Katić" <ivan@devexus.net>
To: <******ada0@gmail.com>
Subject: Checking how are you
Date: Sun, 25 Feb 2018 16:51:40 +0100
Message-ID: <001301d3ae50$875fb710$961f2530$@devexus.net>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0014_01D3AE58.E924E260"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 15.0
Thread-Index: AdOuUH8IeFWERzCMR9u6GZm4/M8Ohg==
Content-Language: hr
```

Checked IP, it isn't blacklisted anywhere.

So what could still be the problem?

Is the problem maybe something with "Received From" and hosts and hostname?

Is the "mail.devexus.net" the problem? Should I remove mail. and only leave with devexus.net?

This is being hosted on linode, could that be a problem?

I'm seriously going crazy here, it's been 2-3 days of trying to figure this :/

Comment: No reputation and spammy looking message (subject looks suspicious, at least), would be my guess. Very possible that there's nothing wrong technically.

Comment: Sometimes the only thing to do is to click "Not Spam". A lot of times.